# Creating a Linked List from File Input

Tags: c, linked-list

Basically what I'm trying to do is take in a txt file and create a linked list off of it. The txt file contains either a "i" or "d" followed by a space and then a number.

Example of txt file:

```
i 10
i 12
d 10
i 5
```

I am trying to take in the input file and based off the input create a linked list. If the letter is an "i", I am trying to add it to the linked list. If it is a "d", I am trying to delete it from the list.

This is what I have so far. I have taken in the file and read it line by line, separating the letters from the number and stores them in char pointers. I tried earlier to create a linked list but it did not work out properly. Could someone please point me in the right direction on where and how I should implement the linked list.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node { // creation of node structure 
        int data; // data inside node
        struct node *next; // address to the next node int the list
        };

void Insert (struct node *root, int x){ // this method will insert a node into the linked list
        struct node *newnode;
        newnode  = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));            
        newnode->data=x;
        newnode->next = NULL; // this creates the node and stores the input into the data variable

        if (root == NULL){ // if the root node is empty, point the root node to this pointer.
            root = newnode;
        }
        else {
        newnode->next=root; // if the link list is not empty, set whatever head point was pointing to previously equal to newnode-> next
        root=newnode; // now make the head node point to the newnode
        }
}        

void printlist(struct node *root)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=root;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
    printf("%d",temp->data);
    temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}           

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    // Need to create a Root Node 
    struct node *root;      

    if (argc != 2) { // if the input is more than one, error
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // argv[1] will contain the file name input. 

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    // we need to make sure the file is not empty, error case. 

    if (file == NULL){ 
        printf("error\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    // if the file is empty, print an empty line. ******** MAKE SURE TO COME BACK TO THIS ************


    char linestring[BUFSIZ]; // this will hold our file input after we read/scan it.

    // now we need to read the file

    while (fgets(linestring, sizeof(linestring), file)) // reads the entire file until it hits Null
    { 
        // need to split up the lines so that we separate letters from integars. 
        // look for \t or " " and use strtok. 

        char* letter = strtok(linestring, " \t\n"); // stores the letter from the line
        char* number = strtok(NULL, " \t\n"); // stores the numbers from the line


        // now we need to now check the letter and see whether it is an "i" or a "d"
        // use sting compare (it returns a 0 if the letter is equal to what we are checking)

        if (strcmp(letter, "i") == 0){ // This checks the letter and if it is "i", we are going to be inserting a node

            // need to create the new node to be inserted and assign the number value to it.
            int x;
            x = atoi(number);   // converts the string input into a integar 
            Insert(root, x); // method which inserts the input onto the linked list. 
        }


        if (strcmp(letter, "d") == 0){ // This checks the letter and if it is "d", we are going to be deleting a node
        }
    }

printlist(root);
fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: you mean if there is "i 10 " then 10 need to be inserted and "d 10" means find 10 in the link list and then delete it... ??

Comment: Your structure looks adequate. What do you mean by, *I tried earlier to create a linked list but it did not work out properly*? Perhaps you could show what you tried and explain the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. For preference, please indent the code systematically, using spaces instead of tabs and usually 4 spaces per level of indent (but being systematic is more important than the size of indent).  Omit commented out code, please.  You should show what you tried with the linked list -- we'll help you fix it, but won't create it for you from scratch. (All else apart, there are many similar questions on SO with fully worked answers.)  Does the code you have read the file correctly?

Comment: forget the reading file thing. then implement a simple link list. you may gonna need insert(),search() and delete() functions.
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/LACRko23/
or 
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42958/linkedlist-with-node-implementation

Comment: Good news; the code you've got reads the data accurately.  So, all you have to do is implement the linked list code.

Comment: I will show how i implement the link list and what it outputs in a moment

Comment: I edited my post above, this is what i have and it is not currently working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that values does not repeated.

```
struct node 
{ // creation of node structure 
        int data; // data inside node
        struct node *next; // address to the next node int the list
};
//insertion in last 
int insertNode(node **root, node *data)
{
    if(!data) return 0; 
    //check if root available. if not data will be the root
    if(!*root)
    {
        *root = data;
        data->next = NULL;
        return 1;
    }
    node *temp = *root;
    while(temp->next)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = data;

    return 1;
}
//deletion. if multiple ocures first will delete
int deleteNode(node **root, int num)
{
    if(!root) return 0;
    node *temp = *root;
    if(temp->data == num)
    {
        if(temp->next)
        {
            *root = temp->next;
        }
        free(temp);
        return 1;
    }
    while(temp->next)
    {
        node* deleteThis = temp->next;
        if((temp->next->next) && temp->next->data == num)
        {
            //delete next            
            temp->next = temp->next->next;
            free(deleteThis);
            return 1;
        }
        else if(temp->next->data == num)
        {
            //the last node
            temp->next = NULL;
            free(deleteThis);
            return 1;
        }
        temp = temp->next;            
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //make root node 
    node* root = NULL;
    // if the input is more than one, error
    if (argc != 2) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // argv[1] will contain the file name input. 

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    // we need to make sure the file is not empty, error case. 

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    // if the file is empty, print an empty line.

    /*int size = ftell(file);
    if (size == 0){
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%d",size);*/

    char linestring[BUFSIZ]; // this will hold our file input after we read/scan it.

    // now we need to read the file

    while (fgets(linestring, sizeof(linestring), file)) // reads the entire file until it hits Null
    {
       // printf("%s", linestring); // stores each line into linestring. 


         // need to split up the lines so that we separate letters from integars. 
         // look for \t or " " and use strtok. 

        char* letter = strtok(linestring, " \t\n"); // stores the letter from the line
        char* number = strtok(NULL, " \t\n"); // stores the numbers from the line
        //changed from here
        int n =atoi(number);//convert string to int
        if(*letter == 'i')
        {
            //creates node to be inserted 
            node *data = NULL;
            data  = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));            
            data->data = n; 
            data->next = NULL;

            if(!insertNode(&root,data)) //if insertion gose wrong 0 will return
                printf("insert %s was faild\n", number); 
        }
        else
        {
            if(!deleteNode(&root,n))
                printf("Couldnt Delete (%s not in the list)\n )", number); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is outputting nothing. I am not sure why it is not working. Can you please help me.

Answer (score -1):

```
**FULL WORKING CODE IN C++ FOR REFERENCE**

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
int data;
struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node node;
typedef struct node* nodeptr;

nodeptr Create(nodeptr head,nodeptr &current,int x){

nodeptr temp = (nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(node));
temp->next=NULL;
temp->data=x;

if(current==NULL){
current=temp;
head=temp;
}

else{
current->next=temp;
current=temp;
}

return head;
}

nodeptr Delete(nodeptr head, int x){

nodeptr temp = head;
nodeptr temp1;

while(temp->data!=x){
    temp1=temp;
    temp=temp->next;
}

temp1->next=temp->next;
free(temp);
temp=NULL;

return head;
}

void PrintC(nodeptr head){

nodeptr temp = head;

while(temp!=NULL){
    cout<<temp->data<<" ";
    temp=temp->next;
}

}

int main(){

nodeptr current = NULL;
nodeptr head = current;

string str;

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("file.txt",ios::out);
myfile << "i 1 i 2 i 3 i 4 i 5 d 2 d 3";
myfile.close();

ifstream myfile1("file.txt");
getline(myfile1,str);
myfile1.close();

int i=0;

while(str[i]!='\0'){

    if(str[i]!=' '){

           if(str[i]=='i'){

                int n = str[i+2]-48;
                head=Create(head,current,n);
                i=i+2;
           }

            else if(str[i]=='d'){

                int n = str[i+2]-48;
                head = Delete(head,n);
                i=i+2;
            }

    }

i++;
}

cout<<endl;

PrintC(head);

return 0;
}
```